# Using Merge Divided Roads "out_table"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I can't figure out how to use the processing tool "merge divided roads" to summarize all feature information. I have a two-line road, sharing a road number. Both lines are separate and have their unique OBJECTID and also an attribute of interest to me - Flow volume. Flow volume tells me how much goods has travelled on the line of the road.

[image]

I would like to make these two lines into one, and I can do that geometrically with merge divided roads sucessfully:

[image]

But the new line only carries the flow attribute from one of the original lines. In the tool, an "out_table" can be generated, supposedly enabling me to generate the sum that i need. I just cant figure out how to use it.

It looks like this:

[image]

I can't figure out what to do with that. I guess I should use a join, but I've tried and I can't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

**If your roads layer does NOT contain intersecting roads:**

Use Spatial Join with a ONE-TO-MANY relationship between the pink lines (target features) and the blue lines (join features) and a relative Match Option (i.e., within a distance). This will create a new layer, which will be the same as the pink lines, but they will have the attributes of the blue lines attached to them. For that new layer, use Summary statistics. In Statistics Field choose "Flow volume", in Statistic type use "MEAN". In the Case Field, use "OBJECTID", or any unique identifier field of the pink lines layer.

**If your roads layer CONTAINS intersecting roads:**

You will have problem with spatial join, because the pink lines will be joined with more than 2 of the blue lines. If they do, make a buffer layer for the pink lines, with a distance greater than the distance between the pink and the blue line. Make sure that each feature of the generated buffer layer completely contains its two corresponding blue roads. Next, use Spatial Join between the buffer layer (target features) and the blue lines (join features) using a Match Option of "Completely Contains". Then, for the output of Spatial Join, use Summary Statistics in the same way as before. Finally, make a join between the pink lines layer and the output layer of Summary Statistics, so that every desired attribute is transfered to the pink lines layer.

Comment: So you're suggesting to not use the ouput table at all?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Merge Divided Tools and its output table. If you provide a full screenshot, explaining each field, then maybe I could think of a simpler solution. What I proposed above yes, completely overlooks the output table.